# Tan() function returns wrong value

Tags: php, math, formula, trigonometry

I got a problem with some code, but can't find the error.
I'm trying to calculate the distance marked in red on the sketch below.

My code return the value: -41.63

Correct value is: 3.75

My code:

```
return round(6.5 * tan(30),2);
```

Based on:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.tan.php

[image]

I thought was was going to be a simple task, but i hit a wall - can't see the error.
I hope some of you can point me in the right direction.

Thanks,

Kenneth

Comment: You need radians ! not degrees ! echo round(6.5 * tan(0.523599), 2);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The arg parameter is in radians.

**[tan()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.tan.php)**

You're sending the number of Degrees and the function expect Radians, so convert your value from Degrees to Radians first and you will get the expected result.

```
return round(6.5 * tan(deg2rad(30)),2);   //3.75
```

**[Fiddle](https://eval.in/768119)**

Answer (score 2):

Your current value is number of degrees and you need to convert this to radians first. Use `deg2rad()` function inside `tan()` to convert value from Degrees into Radians.

[`deg2rad()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.deg2rad.php): Converts the number in degrees to the radian equivalent